# SQL OOP problem : Too many actual parameters on output

Tags: delphi, oop

Please help with the following:

> ERROR : too many actual parameters on calling class procedure line.

Main UNIT:

```
procedure TForm1.btnbtbtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  bwagwoord,bemail :boolean ;
  epos,wagwoord,safvoer :String ;
begin
  Form2.qryreg.Close;
  form2.qryreg.SQL.Text := 'select * from registertb ';
form2.qryreg.open ;

epos := edt1.text ;
wagwoord := edt2.text ;
safvoer := ' ';
bemail :=form2.qryreg.locate ('Email',epos,[]);
bwagwoord := form2.qryreg.Locate('Wagwoord',wagwoord,[]);


Login.create(epos,wagwoord,bepos,bwagwoord);
Login.toetslog(safvoer);
showmessage(safvoer);
end;
```

CLASS:

```
unit cls_login;

interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Menus, StdCtrls, Buttons, math, ExtCtrls;
type
Tlogin = class(Tobject)

private

Fepos :string ;
fwagwoord :string ;
Fbepos : Boolean;
fbwagwoord : Boolean;


Constructor Create(epos,wagwoord:String;bepos, bwagwoord: boolean);
procedure toetslog(var safvoer :string );
public
end;
implementation

{ Tlogin }
constructor Tlogin.Create(epos, wagwoord: String;bepos, bwagwoord: boolean);
begin
fepos := epos ;
fwagwoord := wagwoord ;
fbepos := bepos;
fbwagwoord := bwagwoord;
end;
procedure Tlogin.toetslog( var safvoer :String );
begin

if (fbepos = True) and (fbwagwoord = True)
then
begin
safvoer := 'Welcome '+' '+fepos
 end
else
safvoer := 'SORRY VERKEERD HEHE'+' '+fwagwoord ;
end;

end.
```

Comment: And which line in all this code produces the error? Please mark it by adding some comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I have been wading through your poorly formatted code, and I think I found the problem. Your question did not make it easy, though: as I said, your code shows poor formatting and the error message is probably wrong too. If the code had been formatted, and the error reported literally, the problem would have been rather obvious.

Your constructor `TLogin.Create()` and your method `TLogin.toetslog()` **are both private**. If you try to call them from another unit, they are not accessible. So, from the main unit, the only valid constructor is Create without parameters. If you call Create with parameters, then you will get the error `"Too many parameters on call to..."` or similar.

Do it this way:

```
type
  TLogin = class(TObject)
  private
    Fepos: string;
    Fwagwoord: string ;
    Fbepos: Boolean;
    Fbwagwoord: Boolean;
  public
    constructor Create(epos, wagwoord: string; bepos, bwagwoord: Boolean);
    procedure ToetsLog(var safvoer: string);
  end;
```

And call the constructor this way:

```
  Login := TLogin.Create(epos, wagwoord, bepos, bwagwoord);
```

Comment: sorry for the poor code formstting, im a kid from south-africa

Comment: I had already expeted you were from South-Africa, because of names like `wagwoord`, etc. but even kids can format properly. <g>

Comment: Please help here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141327/acess-violation-delphi-program/7141374#7141374

Comment: @joHno: Apparently you don't read what people write. Your problem there is that you did ***not*** do what I told you to do. I, and others here, told you to create the login using `Login := TLogin.Create(etc..);` and yet you didn't. **And really, format your code before you post it again**. It is not that hard. Just indent lines properly, remove unnecessary empty lines, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to match the error message with the code but I think you're using/creating  the Login object wrong.

```
  //Login.create(epos,wagwoord,bepos,bwagwoord);
  Login := TLogin.create(epos,wagwoord,bepos,bwagwoord);
```

Comment: Well spotted, though I don't think it addresses the problem of the too many actual parameters error...

Comment: I have never seen that error message. It doesn't look like Delphi. Or it was not quoted properly. There is no class procedure, and Delphi wouldn't mention a line.

Comment: @Rudy: The constructor is a class method (sort of). But there is indeed no literal quote of the error.

Comment: I think I found the problem, see my answer.