# Access violation Delphi program

Tags: delphi, oop, access-violation

Please help me with the following code. I get a Access violation from delphi once I click the Log IN button.... Indicated by the  !!!

LogIn Unit

```
unit Log;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls,cls_LogIn,Jpeg;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    lbllogIn: TLabel;
    pnlSplitter: TPanel;
    edtUserName: TEdit;
    edtPassword: TEdit;
    lblUserName: TLabel;
    lblPassword: TLabel;
    btnLogIn: TButton;
    btnRegister: TButton;
    lblRegister: TLabel;
    edtRegName: TEdit;
    edtRegSurname: TEdit;
    edtRegPassword: TEdit;
    edtCountry: TEdit;
    edtHomelanguage: TEdit;
    btnRegisterF: TButton;
    btnCancel: TButton;
    lblRegName: TLabel;
    lblRegSurname: TLabel;
    lblRegPassword: TLabel;
    lblCountry: TLabel;
    lblHomelanguage: TLabel;
    imgLinks: TImage;
    imgRegs: TImage;
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure btnLogInClick(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public

    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;
  Login : Tlogin;
implementation

uses Main;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
Application.Terminate;

end;

procedure TForm2.btnLogInClick(Sender: TObject);   **!!!!!!!!**
var

bUser,bPassword : Boolean;
sUser,sPassword,sMessage : string;
begin
  form1.qrymain.close  ;
Form1.Qrymain.sql.text := 'select * from Gebruikers';
form1.qryMain.open;

sUser := edtUserName.Text;
sPassword := edtpassword.text;
bUser :=  form1.qrymain.locate('Username',sUser,[]);
bPassword := form1.qrymain.locate('Password',sPassword,[]);
Login.create;
login.create(sUser,sPassword,bUser,bPassword);
sMessage:= Login.toetslog;
ShowMessage(sMessage);

end;
```

Class Unit:

```
unit cls_LogIn;

interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Menus, StdCtrls, Buttons, math, ExtCtrls;
type
Tlogin = class(Tobject)

private

Fepos :string ;
fwagwoord :string ;
Fbepos : Boolean;
fbwagwoord : Boolean;
public
constructor create; overload;
constructor Create(epos,wagwoord:String;bepos, bwagwoord: boolean); overload; 

function toetslog: string;


end;
implementation

{ Tlogin }



constructor Tlogin.Create(epos, wagwoord: String;bepos, bwagwoord: boolean);
begin
fepos := epos ;
fwagwoord := wagwoord ;
fbepos := bepos;
fbwagwoord := bwagwoord;
end;


constructor Tlogin.create;
begin
 fepos:= ' ';
 fwagwoord := ' ';
 fbepos := false;
 fbwagwoord := true;
end;

function Tlogin.toetslog;
begin

if (fbepos = True) and (fbwagwoord = True)
then
begin
result := 'Welcome '+' '+fepos
 end
else
result := 'SORRY VERKEERD HEHE'+' '+fwagwoord ;
end;


end.
end.
```

Comment: on which line is the AV?

Comment: It shows on the "end." where the program is inisialized... eg. application.createform......... ''end.''

Comment: @joHno, it's a good programming practice to name functions/procedures/variable etc. in english. Use comments as much as possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL OOP problem : Too many actual parameters on output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138004/sql-oop-problem-too-many-actual-parameters-on-output)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Skip login.create and correct next line to :

```
login := TLogin.Create(sUser,sPassword,bUser,bPassword);
```

the login object should be freed when the login is ready as well.

Like this :

```
login := TLogin.Create(sUser,sPassword,bUser,bPassword);
try
  sMessage := login.toetslog;
  ShowMessage(sMessage);
finally
  login.free;
end;
```

Comment: thanx... still getting the AV

Comment: Then you have inserted that line wrongly. Apart from the horrible formatting and the access of components on Form1, there is nothing wrong with the rest of the code you provided.

Comment: This seems to be the same problem as in your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/7138004/95954), and there, people, including me, already told you to use `Login := TLogin.Create(sUser, sPassword, bUser, bPassword);`.